# Line plot is filled in Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am using pandas and matplotlib to plot a data set.
I am trying to plot two values in a DataFrame a a line plot, but The plot is displaying filled.[image: Dont want this!]

but I want this:
[image: Want this!!!]

my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
covid = pd.read_csv('covid_19_india.csv')
#covid.head()
plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')
plt.plot(covid.Date, covid.Deaths)
```

Help needed from community!

Comment: Try this: `plt.plot(covid.Index, covid.Deaths)`

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I want to compare the two values, like I want to see deaths with respect to the dates.